# Flutter: Why doesn't this streambuilder work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

So, I have just began working on a flutter project and am quite new to the whole experience. I just managed to integrate firebase firestore into my project by creating a few buttons that update, remove, and add documents. However, I also wanted to add a Streambuilder with the list that is being updated on the same page. I tried each task seperately, and they all work fine and dandy, however when I combine the two, the streambuilder shows no data and the buttons won't click. How do I incorporate both buttons and a Streambuilder in one body, or one page? What can I do to combine both of these elements onto one page in the widget build method? Again, the two elements seem to be working okay by themselves if I use the Streambuilder in the body and not a children widget tag.

A picture of what the not working page looks like. Notice how the buttons are not being selected when hovered over and the streambuilder is loading infinitely: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnfVJ.png
Firebase data screenshot (security settings allow users to access the data): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSsOL.png

Here is my code for main.dart:

```
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FireStore Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

        children: <Widget>[

          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Create Record'),
            onPressed: () {
              createRecord();
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('View Record'),
            onPressed: () {
              getData();
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Update Record'),
            onPressed: () {
              updateData();
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Delete Record'),
            onPressed: () {
              deleteData();
            },
          ),
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: databaseReference.collection('books').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
          return new ListView(
            children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              return new ListTile(
                title: new Text(document['title']),
                subtitle: new Text('${document['description']} description'),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      )
        ],
      )),
       //center
    );
  }

  void createRecord() async {
    await databaseReference.collection("books")
        .document("1")
        .setData({
          'title': 'Mastering Flutter',
          'description': 'Programming Guide for Dart'
        });

    DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("books")
        .add({
          'title': 'Flutter in Action',
          'description': 'Complete Programming Guide to learn Flutter'
        });
    print(ref.documentID);
  }

  void getData() {
    databaseReference
        .collection("books")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => print('${f.data}}'));
    });
  }

  void updateData() {
    try {
      databaseReference
          .collection('books')
          .document('1')
          .updateData({'description': 'Head First Flutter'});
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void deleteData() {
    try {
      databaseReference
          .collection('books')
          .document('1')
          .delete();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Run put breakpoint on `if(!snapshot.hasData)` and run in debug mode to check if it's running or not.

Comment: It isn't working or it isn't showing new data in your builder? I am asking that because I didn't see any setstate in your functions.

Comment: Also try to put `StreamBuilder` inside `Container` as child element.

Comment: It isn't showing any data in the builder, and the buttons don't seem to work

Comment: And It is work if you use only StreamBuilder in body without buttons at this page?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of relevant data in firebase that you are trying to query and do you get any error when you createRecord?

Comment: Yes, if I use Streambuilder in body it works

Comment: Added a screenshot of firebase. No error when I createRecord when there is no streambuilder, when there is a streambuilder the button doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by button don't work? Is it not updating the data in the database or not updating the UI?

Comment: both... the ui doesn't update when clicked or hovered on, and the data is not updating in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still don't know why the code above didn't work, but putting the streambuilder within an Expanded block seemed to do the trick! Both widgets are working fine as of now.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MediaQuery(
    data: new MediaQueryData(), child: new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp())));

```
      child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

    children: <Widget>[

      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Create Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          createRecord();
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('View Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          getData();
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Update Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          updateData();
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Delete Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          deleteData();
        },
      ),
  new Expanded(child:
    new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: databaseReference.collection('books').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
      return new ListView(
        children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(document['title']),
            subtitle: new Text('${document['description']} description'),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
    )
  )
    ],
  )),
   //center
);
```