# Flutter - StreamBuilder doesn't update the UI

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

The `StreamBuilder` Widget doesn't update the UI ,i still always see the `ChoiceScreen` which contains two buttons `Log In` and `Sign Up` when i click `Sign Up` it takes me to the `SignUpSCreen` , pretty same for the `LoginScreen` , But when i try to Login as a registred User the `StreamBuilder` doesn't update the Ui and show the `ChatScreen` widget unless i re-run the application or do a Hot restart to see the updated UI .

Here's what i tried :

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, userSnap){
              print('stream builder');
              // a valid token
              if(userSnap.hasData){
                print('valid token .. user logged in');
                return ChatScreen();
              }
              print('not yet');
              return ChoiceScreen();
            },
          ),
```

The logic seems working , i got :

```
I/flutter ( 5194): stream builder
I/flutter ( 5194): valid token .. user logged in
```

But it doesn't return the screen i'm expecting ... and i should do Hot restart to see it ,as i mentioned .

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835886/13652942) but the problem persist  ..

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is because you need to 'pop' by using `Navigate.pop()` You see, since you have both auth screens in `ChoiceScreen`, you need to pop out of there, once you do you it will be able to navigate itself correctly. So, right after they enter their credentials, pop the widget off. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html

Comment: Why don't you use the Navigator class?

Comment: Thanks guys,
Yeah i know about `Navigator` , i don't need it , because i assign it to the body property of the `Scaffold` .

Comment: @Unbreachable Thanks, Yeah i should always go back `pop` the `LoginScreen` to see the `ChatScreen` ... So can i solve that without popping it ?

Comment: Basically i want the `ChatScreen` to push above the `LoginScreen` or `SignUp` screen

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to initialize a variable.
For example,

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, userSnap){
              print('stream builder');
              var data = usersSnap.data;
            
              if(data.hasData){
                print('valid token .. user logged in');
                return ChatScreen();
              }
              print('not yet');
              return ChoiceScreen();
            },
          ),
```